# Format from TinyMCE editor will not be sent via E-Mail using PHP-Mailer

Tags: php, email, tinymce, phpmailer

Alright, I have been searching for days, and I can't get it to work correctly.
I am using a modal to show a form, where people should be able to enter Name, an identifier, choose a recipient, add an attachment and - enter text, which they can format (tinymce).
Whatever I have tried, the content comes as plain text - no format at all.
I am sure, it might be only a little mistake, and most of you will be like "stop throwing code together like a maniac" - yet still, I have no idea where to search or what to search for even.
Any help would be highly appreciated. Sorry for the bad formatting of the lower part - even here, I don't get it to work, I really appreciate anyone's help!

Here is the code from the page:

This is the tinyMCE-Editor

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/zx5yw56lg534zm3hbmekc4i7ex3y27nu7qi3nyrszogdohz3/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
    <script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector:'#editor',
        
        // If we don't need the menubar or statusbar we can hide them
        // https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#menubar
        // https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#statusbar
        menubar: false,
        statusbar: false,

        // Tip! To make TinyMCE leaner, only include the plugins you actually need.
        plugins: 'autoresize lists',

        // This option allows you to specify the buttons and the order that they
        // will appear on TinyMCE’s toolbar.
        // https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#toolbar
        toolbar: 'bold italic strikethrough blockquote bullist numlist | fullscreen ',

        // We use the Bootstrap premium skin to make TinyMCE match the
        // visual style of Bootstrap, primarily colors and the dialogs.
        // You can also create your own bootstrap skin.
        // https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/enterprise/premium-skins-and-icon-packs/outside-demo/
        // https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#skin
        // https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/creating-a-skin/
        skin: 'bootstrap',

        // Setting the minimum height when using the autoresize plugin
        // https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#min_height
        min_height: 400,

        // Set the whitespace between the bottom most row and the bottom of the editor
        // https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/autoresize/#autoresize_bottom_margin
        autoresize_bottom_margin: 20,

        // To make sure the toolbar never scrolls out of view which can happen when
        // writing very long texts while using the autoresize plugin. This option
        // sticks the toolbar to the top of the screen while the editable area
        // is visible
        // https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#toolbar_sticky
        toolbar_sticky: true,

        setup: (editor) => {
            // Apply the Bootstrap focus outline and associated animation
            // Read more about different editor events in the documentation
            // https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/events/
            editor.on('init', () => {
                // https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#getcontainer
                editor.getContainer().style.transition="border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out"
            });
            editor.on('focus', () => {
                editor.getContainer().style.boxShadow="0 0 0 .2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, .25)",
                editor.getContainer().style.borderColor="#80bdff"
            });
            editor.on('blur', () => {
                editor.getContainer().style.boxShadow="",
                editor.getContainer().style.borderColor=""
            });
        }
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
```

Here comes the Modal-Form

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-3 ml-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    Schick uns deine I-Story
</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
<?php if(empty($msg)){ ?>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="container" id="needs-validation" novalidate>
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">I-Story-Formular</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Name">
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    Bitte gib deinen Namen ein.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="Text" class="form-control" name="ibc" placeholder="Consultant-Nummer">
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    Bitte gib deine Consultantnummer an.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <select name="to" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="sales">Contact us</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="reason" id="editor" rows="7" required=""></textarea>
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    Trage hier bitte deine I-Story ein.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <!--     <input type="file" name="attachment">   -->
                                 <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" required="" value="10000000"> Bild anfügen (Max. 10 MB!): <input name="attachment" type="file">
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    Bitte füge ein Bild hinzu...
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Schließen</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="feedback">I-Story abschicken</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php }else{ 
    echo $msg;
} ?>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    (function() {
        'use strict';
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        var form = document.getElementById('needs-validation');
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            }
            form.classList.add('was-validated');
        }, false);
        }, false);
    })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally the php-mailer (in my code on top)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require("src/PHPMailer.php");
require("src/SMTP.php");
require("src/Exception.php");

if (array_key_exists('to', $_POST)) {
$err = false;
$msg = '';
$email = '';

//Apply some basic validation and filtering to the query
if (array_key_exists('reason', $_POST)) {
    //Limit length and strip HTML tags
    $reason = substr(strip_tags($_POST['reason']), 0, 16384);
} else {
    $reason = '';
    $msg = 'No feedback provided!';
    $err = true;
}
//Apply some basic validation and filtering to the name
if (array_key_exists('username', $_POST)) {
    //Limit length and strip HTML tags
    $username = substr(strip_tags($_POST['username']), 0, 255);
} else {
    $username = '';
}
//Validate to address
//Never allow arbitrary input for the 'to' address as it will turn your form into a spam gateway!
//Substitute appropriate addresses from your own domain, or simply use a single, fixed address
if (array_key_exists('to', $_POST)) {
    $to =  'myself@work.com';
}
    if (array_key_exists('attachment', $_FILES)) {
    $img_name = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];
    $upload = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['attachment']['name']));
    $uploadfile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/comcloud/istory/mail/assets/img/'.$img_name;
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        if (!$err) {
            $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
            $mail->isSMTP();
            // $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.something.de';
            // set a port
            $mail->Port = 587;
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            // set login detail for smtp account
            $mail->Username = 'whatever';
            $mail->Password = 'private';
            $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
            // set subject
            $mail->setFrom('mail@something.de');
            $mail->addAddress($to);
            $mail->addReplyTo('mail@spomething.de');
            $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile);
            $mail->IsHTML(true);
            $mail->Subject = ($_POST['ibc']);
            $mail->Body = $reason;
            if (!$mail->send()) {
                $msg .= "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            } else {
                $msg .= "I-Story erfolgreich abgeschickt!";
                header("Refresh:3; url=index.php");
           }
        }
    } else {
                $msg .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
    }
 }
}   
?>    
</html>
```

Comment: To clarify, when you say, "the content comes as plain text - no format at all." do you mean that the content does not contains HTML tags at all, or that the format/style applied in TinyMCE is being not applied to the HTML of editor content?

Comment: See below - I had simply stripped out everyhting and was wondering, why that happened :( Stupid me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might seem blindingly obvious, but you're doing this:

```
$reason = substr(strip_tags($_POST['reason']), 0, 16384);
...
$mail->Body = $reason;
```

So you're deliberately stripping all HTML tags from your message body. Not surprisingly, this will result in a plain-text message.

You should sanitise your HTML since it's user-supplied (and thus potentially malicious), though that is not an easy thing to do – look at things like HTML Purifier and htmlAwed to help with that.

Comment: Like I said: I am sure, it might be only a little mistake

That absolutely was the issue - I thank you very much, @Synchro !